# Disabling back ground of the popup using angularjs without using bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-style

I want to have a popup and the background screen disabled using only divs, ng-class, ng-style and css3 styles. I DO NOT WANT TO USE BOOTSTRAP MODAL. I have been struggling to get this work. I am trying to show and hide the popup but all its doing is disabling the screen without displaying the popup. Below is the code

Html code

```
<div id="popupBackGround" class="popupModal-backdrop" ng-if="newUser===true" ng-style="{'display': (newUser===false || newUser===undefined) ? 'none':'block'}">
<div id="popupBackGroundDialog" class="popupModal-dialog">
    <div class="popupModal-content">
        <div class="popupModal-body">
           <p style="margin-left: 20px;">
                            <strong>Is this user transferring from another Dept?</strong>
           </p>
           <p style="margin-left: 40px;">
                <input ng-click="" name="transfer" value="Yes" type="radio"> <strong>Yes</strong>
           </p> 
           <p style="margin-left: 40px;">
                <input ng-click="" name="transfer"  value="No" type="radio"> <strong>No</strong>
          </p>
          <p align= "center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
          </p>
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.popupModal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-top: -430px;
  opacity: "0"
}
.popupModal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: none;
}
.popupModal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.popupModal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why all the yelling about Bootstrap? If you want help with AngularJS, show your controller.

Comment: Apologies.. didnt mean to offend bootstrap lovers :-) .. I do not want to use bootstrap modal as we are not allowed to use that and all the online post are related to bootstrap modal. Now there is no logic in controller ...only based on the value newUser it needs to get displayed, I need to display the popup with a deactivated back groud. Please suggest if there is a way to do that without using jquery or javascript

Comment: I rolled back my edit as I may have misunderstood the question. What's the "background" in this case? The modal mask or the other page content?

Comment: It worked with your previous solution.. thanks a lot.. i really did a very silly mistake with the z index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify a bit--you seem to have two mechanisms doing the same job (`ng-if` and `ng-style`).

```
<div ng-app>
  <button ng-click="showModal=1">Show modal</button>

  <div id="popupBackGround" class="popupModal-backdrop" ng-if="showModal"></div>

  <div id="popupBackGroundDialog" class="popupModal-dialog" ng-show="showModal">
    <div class="popupModal-content">
      <div class="popupModal-body">
        <p style="margin-left: 20px;">{{showModal}}</p>
        <p>
          <button ng-click="showModal=0">Hide modal</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/U3pVM/22120/)**

I did simplify your CSS, also.